# Display PDF file Inside Java Program

Tags: java, file-io

Ive been trying to do research on how to display a PDF file inside a Java program, not just opening the PDF. Because I want to make some words inside the PDF (displayed in the program) a Hyperlink so that it would and could open another PDF in the same way.

Is it even possible, or am I on the right track, or is there a better way of doing that... like a method already existing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support in the Java SE API itself to render PDF. Just use some existing library, like: [JPedal](http://www.jpedal.org/open_source_pdf_viewer_download.php).

Answer (score 0):

Whats a PFD do you mean PDF ?

I believe flying saucer may be used to render a PDF to a image which you can then display.

Comment: ah sorry yea i mean PDF. Ohh oky, but then i wont be able to use that image, because i want to use the text in the pdf to turn some of them into hyper links.